# Angular Component Parent Function undefined arguments

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I got a component which binds a parent function. I know I have to use non-primitive values as arguments but I still get undefined. What's going on ? Here's a sample code that demonstrates my problem.

Component:

```
app.component('testComponent', {
  template:'<button ng-click="$ctrl.hasStatus({val:700})">Test</button>',
  bindings:{
    hasStatus:'&'
  },
  controller:function() {
    var ctrl = this;
  }
})
```

Parent:

```
<test-component has-status='hasStatus(statusObj)'></test-component>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.hasStatus = function(obj) {
   console.log(obj) // undefined
}
```

And the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2e4voQhjgDUSScOgj4TI?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your has-status attribute function has `hasStatus(statusObj)`, where `statusObj` is parameter of object. That's why you should pass status `statusObj` property mentioned in JSON, while passing parameter to `hasStatus` method.

```
ng-click="$ctrl.hasStatus({statusObj: { val: 700}})"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Duh1RFbHKR32BdKiyMmX?p=preview)